# Keras Conv1D on ECG Signal

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify different ECG signals. I am using Keras' Conv1D, but am not getting any good results.
I have tried changing the number of layers, window size, etc, but every time I run this I get predictions all of the same class (the classes are 0,1,2, so I get a prediction output of something like [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], but the class changes each time I run the script).
The ECG signals are in 1000 point numpy arrays.

Are there any glaringly obvious things I am doing wrong here? I was thinking it would've worked great to use a few layers to just classify into 3 different ECG signals.

```py
#arrange and randomize data
y1=[[0]]*len(lead1)
y2=[[1]]*len(lead2)
y3=[[2]]*len(lead3)
y=np.concatenate((y1,y2,y3))
data=np.concatenate((lead1,lead2,lead3))
data = keras.utils.normalize(data)
data=np.concatenate((data,y),axis=1)
data=np.random.permutation((data))
print(data)

#separate data and create categories
Xtrain=data[0:130,0:-1]
Xtrain=np.reshape(Xtrain,(len(Xtrain),1000,1))
Xpred=data[130:,0:-1]
Xpred=np.reshape(Xpred,(len(Xpred),1000,1))
Ytrain=data[0:130,-1]
Yt=to_categorical(Ytrain)
Ypred=data[130:,-1]
Yp=to_categorical(Ypred)

#create CNN model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(20,20,activation='relu',input_shape=(1000,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(20,10,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(20,10,activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dense(3,activation='relu',use_bias=False))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(Xtrain,Yt)

#test model
print(model.evaluate(Xpred,Yp))
print(model.predict_classes(Xpred,verbose=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any glaringly obvious things I am doing wrong here?

Indeed there is: the output you report is not surprising, given that you are currently using the ReLU as activation for your last layer, which does not make any sense.

In multi-class settings, such as yours, the activation of the last layer must be the softmax, and certainly not the ReLU; change your last layer to:

```py
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Not quite sure why you ask for `use_bias=False`, but you can try both with and without it and experiment...